# Delete JSON data, if available in main json data

Tags: python, json, delete-operator

I have two json data, where json_main and json1 are shown below. I want to check json1, if any details available in json_main data then that exact details should be deleted and expected results, which I am looking like "Outcome Result_json" shown below.

For example: In json1 data ""fields": {
"Full Address": "data2",
"hz": "text2",
"ot": "doc2"" are available in the json_main data. So I want to delete that from json1 data.

I tried with python code, but I don't know how to make comparison with json_main data and delete in json1 data.

**json_main**

```
 [
  {
    "fields": {
      "Full Address": "data1",
      "hz": "text1",
      "ot": "doc1"
   }
  },
  {
  "fields": {
    "Full Address": "data2",
    "hz": "text2",
    "ot": "doc2"
     }
   }
   ]
```

**json1**

```
 [
  {
    "fields": {
      "Full Address": "data2",
      "hz": "text2",
      "ot": "doc2"
   }
  },
  {
  "fields": {
    "Full Address": "data3",
    "hz": "text3",
    "ot": "doc3"
  }
 }
 ]
```

**Outcome Result_json**

```
 [
  {
  "fields": {
    "Full Address": "data3",
    "hz": "text3",
    "ot": "doc3"
  }
 }
 ]
```

**Python**

```
  with open('writing_file.json', 'w') as w:
  with open('reading_file.json', 'r') as r:
    for line in r:
        element = json.loads(line.strip())
        if 'data2' in element:
            del element['data2']
        w.write(json.dumps(element))
```

Comment: what if only one of the field is same? and why are you explicitly checking for `'data2'`?

Comment: Then resulted outcome give nothing in the json body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to answer my own question. first I will generate the values of "Full Address" from "json_main" as an unique key, which are "data1", "data2".

unique_key =  ["data1", "data2"]

Filtering the data of "json1". Please see the python code below.

**python code**

```
  import json
  import sys
  
  unique_key = [elt["fields"]["Full Address"] for elt in json_main]
  print( unique key)
  Output =  ["data1", "data2"]


  json1 = [
        {
      "fields": {
           "Full Address": "data2",
           "hz": "text2",
           "ot": "doc2"
          }
          },
         {
     "fields": {
           "Full Address": "data3",
           "hz": "text3",
           "ot": "doc3"
               }
               }
             ]


 #  delete json objects.
 data2 = [x for x in json1 if x['fields']['Full Address'] not in unique_key]

 print(data2)

  data2 = [
          {
       "fields": {
           "Full Address": "data3",
           "hz": "text3",
           "ot": "doc3"
                 }
                }
             ]
```